# Why the constrained randomization of UVM does not work?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have some simplified test structure. The testcase `apb_write_verify2y_test` calls `apb_write_verify2y_seq`, then it calls `apb_write_seq`.

However, `m_seq.m_addr=16'h0010` (at `apb_write_verify2y_test`) does not passed to `m_apb_write_seq.m_addr` as it should.

If I change the line in `apb_write_verify2y_seq` like below, then it is working:

```
assert(m_apb_write_seq.randomize() with {m_apb_write_seq.m_addr == 16'h0010;});
```

Can you please help me on this?

```
class apb_write_verify2y_test extends apb_base_test;
    `uvm_component_utils(apb_write_verify2y_test)
    virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
        apb_write_verify2y_seq m_seq;
        phase.raise_objection(.obj(this));
        m_seq = apb_write_verify2y_seq::type_id::create(.name("m_seq"));
        m_seq.m_addr = 16'h0010;
        m_seq.start(m_env.m_apb_agent.m_apb_seqr);
        #10ns ;
        phase.drop_objection(.obj(this));
    endtask: run_phase

class apb_write_verify2y_seq extends uvm_sequence#(apb_seq_item);
    `uvm_object_utils(apb_write_verify2y_seq)
    logic [15:0]  m_addr;
    task body();
        apb_write_seq m_apb_write_seq;
        repeat (2) begin
            m_apb_write_seq = apb_write_seq::type_id::create(.name("m_apb_write_seq"));
            assert(m_apb_write_seq.randomize() with {m_apb_write_seq.m_addr == m_addr;});
            `uvm_info("debug1", $sformatf("m_seq has m_addr=%h, m_apb_write_seq.m_addr=%h", m_addr, m_apb_write_seq.m_addr ), UVM_HIGH);
            m_apb_write_seq.start(m_sequencer);
        end
    endtask: body

class apb_write_seq extends uvm_sequence#(apb_seq_item);
    `uvm_object_utils(apb_write_seq)
    rand logic [15:0]  m_addr;
    task body();
        apb_seq_item m_apb_seq_item;
        m_apb_seq_item = apb_seq_item::type_id::create(.name("m_apb_seq_item"));
        start_item(m_apb_seq_item);
        assert(m_apb_seq_item.randomize() with { m_apb_seq_item.tr_addr == m_addr;});
        finish_item(m_apb_seq_item);
    endtask
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.randomize() with {}` function will first search for the variable in the scope of the object being randomized. If it cannot be be found within the target object, then it will search the local scope from where randomization function is being called. The name `m_addr` exists in `apb_write_verify2y_seq` and `apb_write_seq`. With your current code both `m_addr` is referring to the same variable from `m_apb_write_seq`.

You want to use the `local::` scope operator to tell the randomize to only search the current scope.

```
assert(m_apb_write_seq.randomize() with {m_addr == local::m_addr;});
```

This way `m_addr` is referring to `m_apb_write_seq` scope, and `local::m_addr` is referring to `apb_write_verify2y_seq` scope.

Comment: ， Hi Greg, Thanks for the answer. I tried, it is working. I have also tried a bit, If I put it like {m_addr==apb_cfg::m_addr;}, this is also working.

Comment: If I remove 'm_apb_write_seq',  where does m_addr refer to?

Comment: Changing  `m_apb_write_seq.randomize()` to `randomize()` would mean the object randomizes itself, therefore it would refer to its own m_addr